# Ограничение запросов от телеграмма

Tags: telegram, aiogram, api, сервер

столкнулся с проблемой:

aiogram.utils.exceptions.RetryAfter: Flood control exceeded. Retry in 5 seconds.

Так вот я провел тесты и увидел что для группы больше 11 запросов бот не отправляет выводит ошибку флуда. Так вот в API сказано что можно отправить 20 запросов может я что то не так делаю?. Бот написан на aiogram 2.25.1

0

хотел бы дополнить у меня к примеру в группе запускаются 2 сообщения которые редактируются два раза с интервалом в 6-8 секунд также это сообщение могут запустить 2 пользователя в чате. И второе часто используемое стоит с интервалом в 1.5-3 секунды на рандом. И если присоединяется, 3 участник то бот уже начинает выдавать ошибку